# Bash local AND readonly variable

Tags: bash

I like to organize my code with functions, as I am using function I like to use `local` variables also. As much as possible I use `read-only` variables, so if I make any mistake inside my code it will be easily noticed.

But I have been using it wrong for a long time. So I decided to write it to share my experience.

How to define `local` AND `read-only` inside bash function? (See the answer and explanation below).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**First attempt:** `local readonly var1`

That is the way I used to define it. It is wrong. I will define my variable `var1` as `local`, but it will not be `readonly`, as you can see on example below, I can  change the value of `var1`, and I don't want that!

```
:~$ (
>     myfunction()
>     {
>         # Define variable
>         local readonly var1="val1"
>         
>         echo "Readonly output:"
>         readonly | grep -E 'readonly|local|var1'
>         echo ""
> 
>         echo "Local output:"
>         local | grep -E 'readonly|local|var1'
>         echo ""
> 
>         var1="val2"
>         echo "VAR1 INSIDE: ${var1}"
>     }
>     myfunction
>     echo "VAR1 OUTSIDE: ${var1}"
> )
Readonly output:

Local output:
var1=val1

VAR1 INSIDE: val2
VAR1 OUTSIDE:
```

**Second attempt:** `readonly local var1`

This time it will define `var1` as `readonly`, but it will also define a variable called `local`, so using this way it will not handle `local` as keyword, it will be a variable name.

Check also that the scope of `var1` is not `local`, in fact it is `global`, we can see the value of `var1` outside the function.

```
:~$ (
>     myfunction()
>     {
>         # Define variable
>         readonly local var1="val1"
>         
>         echo "Readonly output:"
>         readonly | grep -E 'readonly|local|var1'
>         echo ""
> 
>         echo "Local output:"
>         local | grep -E 'readonly|local|var1'
>         echo ""
> 
>         echo "VAR1 INSIDE: ${var1}"
>     }
>     myfunction
>     echo "VAR1 OUTSIDE: ${var1}"
> )
Readonly output:
declare -r local
declare -r var1="val1"

Local output:

VAR1 INSIDE: val1
VAR1 OUTSIDE: val1
```

---

**As it should be:** `local -r var1`

This way it will do exactly what I want, it will define `var1` as scope `local` AND `readonly`.

```
:~$ (
>     myfunction()
>     {
>         # Define variable
>         local -r var1="val1"
>         
>         echo "Readonly output:"
>         readonly | grep -E 'readonly|local|var1'
>         echo ""
> 
>         echo "Local output:"
>         local | grep -E 'readonly|local|var1'
>         echo ""
> 
>         #var1="val2"
>         echo "VAR1 INSIDE: ${var1}"
>     }
>     myfunction
>     echo "VAR1 OUTSIDE: ${var1}"
> )
Readonly output:
declare -r var1="val1"

Local output:
var1=val1

VAR1 INSIDE: val1
VAR1 OUTSIDE:
```

We can define it as below also, but one line is better than two!

```
local var1="val1"
readonly var1
```

Comment: Thank you for finding and explaining this. The fact that bash allows you to declare something `local readonly` and shows no errors is... infuriating. Without this, I would've assumed it worked correctly.

Comment: One other note: on Ubuntu 18.04, using `local -r` with arrays seems to not properly scope things, so if you have two functions with two `local -r` arrays with the same name, you get an error. The workaround for arrays is to use `local -ar`.

Comment: @YevgeniyBrikman How about you post an answer with some demo code about this? So it is easy for people to see and reproduce it. If possible, try to show also the difference between `local -a` (indexed array) and `local -A` (associative array).

Comment: FYI when using `local readonly var1` you just end up declaring 2 local variables named respectively "readonly" and "var1". You can use `declare -p` (thanks https://askubuntu.com/a/277969/911295) to see what variables are defined.

Comment: This (detecting `local readonly ...`) would probably make a good ShellCheck feature request.

Comment: @dimo414 Actually, _ShellCheck_ is giving hints that "_`readonly` appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally). shellcheck([SC2034](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2034))_"

Comment: @SnzFor16Min sure but that's not the actual issue, just a related finding. It looks like [SC2316](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2316) was recently added to flag this exact situation though!

Comment: It's important to remember that shell is not a programming language.  something like 'local' is a command, not a keyword.  If you look at its args iwith 'help local' it takes a list of variables, so 'local readonly x' means  "set up two variables, readonly, and x, as locals'

readonly is similar.

I agree it would be a decent thing for shellcheck to flag, but if you think like a shell user you would probably never write such a thing in the first place.

Answer (score 16):

The bash man page summarizes things thusly for the `declare` command:

```
    -r   Make names readonly.  These names cannot then be assigned values
         by subsequent assignment statements or unset.
```

and

```
   When used in a function, declare and typeset make each name local, as with
   the local command, unless the -g option is supplied.
```

So if you `declare` within a function, the variable you declare will be local by default. And if you use the `-r` option, it will be read-only.

```
$ cat testv
#!/usr/bin/env bash

test1() {
  declare -r var="$1"
  var="bacon"
}

s=foo
test1 bar
echo "$s - $var"

$ bash testv
testv: line 5: var: readonly variable
foo -
```

Comment: What is the difference between `declare -r` and `local -r` inside a function?

Comment: One of them uses two bytes less than the other one to store the command in your script. Oh, and the other one starts with a "d". :)

Comment: @Azize: local reads better.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see, *local* *readonly* *variables* in bash are not so local:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -r TESTVAR="global"

testlocalvar()
{
    declare -r TESTVAR="local"
    echo "${TESTVAR}"
}

echo "${TESTVAR}"
testlocalvar
echo "${TESTVAR}"
```

Output is:

```
+ ./test.sh
global
./test.sh: line 7: declare: TESTVAR: readonly variable
global
global
```

So, Is it possible to declare really *local readonly variable* in bash function with same name as in global context, readonly one?

This code works as expected:

```
 #!/bin/bash
    
    declare TESTVAR="global"
    
    testlocalvar()
    {
        declare -r TESTVAR="local"
        echo "${TESTVAR}"
    }
    
    echo "${TESTVAR}"
    testlocalvar
    echo "${TESTVAR}"
```

Output is:

```
+ ./test.sh
global
local
global
```

There is a shell...

Is there a way?

Comment: This should be posted as a question, not an answer.

Comment: No. This is an only nuance of the question.

Comment: Then it should be posted as a comment on the question.

Comment: I have no enough privileges to make it possible.